# PHP - Add or Subtract to variable

Tags: php

How can I add or subtract a specified amount to a variable?
I need to have a "wallet" that indicates `500€`. Now if I press a button there is a 50/50 chance that I either get `100€` on top of the `500€` or lose `100€`. It should end if either the wallet gets to `0` or the page gets refreshed. 
(I'm a beginner)

Comment: Unless you've included the `€` in the variable, you should just be able to use `+` and `-` to add or subtract (e.g. `$wallet = $wallet + 100;`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Answer (score 0):

try this simple code.

```
<?php

if($money == ''){
    $money = 500; //initial wallet amount
}

$amount = 100;// it will be added or subtracted

$wallet = $_POST['yourwallet']; //actual wallet value

if(isset($wallet)){ //check if form was submitted

    if($wallet > 0){ //you can play while the wallet value is > 0

        $p = rand(0,99); //probability

        if($p > 49){
            $money = ($wallet) + ($amount);
            echo '<center><b>';
            echo 'You won €100';
            echo '</center></b></br>';
        }else{
            $money = ($wallet) - ($amount);
            echo '<center><b>';
            echo 'You lost €100';
            echo '</center></b></br>';
        }

    }else{ //if wallet gets 0 or less you can't play anymore
            echo '<center><b>';
            echo 'Sorry, you don't have enough money to play again';
            echo '</center></b></br>';
    }
}

?>

<html>
    <center>

    <form method="post">
        Your wallet</br>
        <input type="text" name="yourwallet" readonly value="<?php echo $money ?>" /> </br>
        </br>
        <input value="Click me, you could win €100" type="submit">
    </form>

    </center>
</html>
```